# Why does my SSIS project not deploy from SSDT 2017?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

recently, when I try to deploy my SSIS project from SSDT 2017 I get the following error:

---

Failed to deploy project. For more information, query the operation_messages view for the operation identifier '2'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 27203)

---

Moreover, SSIS does not write any message to "operation_messages" - the table is empty. All I get is a non-descriptive entry in the "operations" view.

I have recently recreated the SSIS DB in order to fix the error (did not work), hence the low count in the "operation_messages" view. We have also restarted the database server.

Has anyone had a similar problem and can point me in the right direction.

Cheers!

Edit: I can run the project from SSDT with no problems.

Edit 2:
If I copy the package to my local machine, it deploys without any
issues. On the server, I get the deployment error, even if I try to deploy a newly created empty package.

Comment: Is your project in the right compatibility for the instance you are deploying to?

Comment: I believe so - The project has TargetServerVersion = "SQL Server 2019" and @@VERSION in SSMS gives me "Microsoft SQL Server 2019"

Comment: Do you have a default value for all parameters in the project? Did you upgrade the SQL Server recently? Is the SQL Server in AG or a stand alone instance?

Comment: I have default values for all parameters and variables (some emtpy strings, but they should be fine?) There were no recent upgrades and the SQL Server is standalone

Comment: Please share output of the `SELECT @@VERSION;` in its entirety on the SSIS run-time server. We need to see the build and what CU you have there.

Comment: The Output is: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU8-GDR) (KB4583459) - 15.0.4083.2 (X64) 
 Nov  2 2020 18:35:09 
 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: We have narrowed down the issue to SSIS using an incorrcet server for deployment. The (possible) solution requires a restart of the instance. I will keep you updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have resolved the problem. The final clue came from the Windwos event log, where we found out that SSDT was trying to deploy to a wrong database ("Database..." instead of "DB..."). The wrong information seems to have been retrieved from the sys.servers table. We updated the wrong information by using

EXEC sp_dropserver 'Database...';
GO
EXEC sp_addserver 'DB...', local;
GO

Now I can deploy the project again. I have no idea how the incorrect information ended up in sys.servers, but this has done the trick. Thanks to everyone who tried to help out!